# Join after outerjoin in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sqlalchemy, outer-join

Suppose I have a one-to-many relationship, where the parents and children are grouped by some `group_id`.

> Note: this example is a stripped down version of my code, which is actually a many-to-many relationship. There may be some errors unrelated to the question.

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(GUID, default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(GUID, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(GUID)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)

class Leaf(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'leaf'
    id = Column(GUID, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(GUID, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(GUID, nullable=False)
```

The `group_id` is used as a way to create new versions - so nodes and leaves with the same `id` can exist in multiple groups.

What I want to do is compare two groups, and find all the leaves whose parents have changed. I am trying to use an outer join to do the comparison, and then two joins to filter the parent nodes:

```
def find_changed_leaves(group_id_a, group_id_b, session):
    NodeA = model.Node
    NodeB = aliased(model.Node, name='node_b')
    LeafA = model.Leaf
    LeafB = aliased(model.Leaf, name='leaf_b')

    query = (session.query(LeafA, LeafB)
        .outerjoin(LeafB, LeafA.id == LeafB.id)

        .join(NodeA, (LeafA.group_id == NodeA.group_id) &
                     (LeafA.parent_id == NodeA.id))
        .join(NodeB, (LeafB.group_id == NodeB.group_id) &
                     (LeafB.parent_id == NodeB.id))

        # Group membership
        .filter(LeafA.group_id == group_id_a,
                LeafB.group_id == group_id_b)

        # Filter for modified parents
        .filter(NodeA.title != NodeB.title)
    )

    return query.all()
```

This works, but it doesn't show leaves that are only in one of the groups (e.g. if a leaf was added to a node in the new group). How can I show all the leaves, returning `None` for a leaf that is missing from one of the groups?

*Edit:* I see there are [perils mixing join with outer join](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/11/mixing-inner-outer-joins-sql.aspx). I tried naively changing it to `.outerjoin(NodeA, ...`, but it didn't help.

Comment: An extended (unit-test like) example case of inputs and desired output would be of tremendous help in order to understand the scope of the comparison you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, it is not entirely clear what needs to be achieved. Nonetheless, the code below should at least give you some directions.

First of all, I would not try to combine it all in one query (potentially using full joins and subqueries), but split it into 3 separate queries:

1. get `LeafA, LeafB` whose' parents have changed
2. get `LaefA` that do not have corresponding `LeafB`
3. get `LaefB` that do not have corresponding `LeafA`

Below is the code which should run as it is in both `sqlite` and `postgresql`. Note that I have added relationships and use them in the queries. But you could do the same with explicit join conditions as in your code snippet.

```
import uuid

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Text, and_,
    ForeignKeyConstraint, UniqueConstraint, exists
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, eagerload, aliased
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID as GUID

_db_uri = 'sqlite:///:memory:'; GUID = String
# _db_uri = "postgresql://aaa:bbb@localhost/mytestdb"
engine = create_engine(_db_uri, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base(engine)

newid = lambda: str(uuid.uuid4())

# define object model
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(GUID, default=newid, primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(GUID, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    # parent_id = Column(GUID)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)


class Leaf(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'leaf'
    id = Column(GUID, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(GUID, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(GUID, nullable=False)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)

    # define relationships - easier test data creation and querying
    parent = relationship(
        Node,
        primaryjoin=and_(Node.id == parent_id, Node.group_id == group_id),
        backref="children",
    )

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['parent_id', 'group_id'], ['node.id', 'node.group_id']
        ),
    )


Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session()


g1, g2, l1, l2, l3 = [newid() for _ in range(5)]

# Create test data
def _add_test_data():
    n11 = Node(
        title="node1", group_id=g1,
        children=[
            Leaf(id=l1, title="g1 only"),
            Leaf(id=l3, title="both groups"),
        ]
    )

    n21 = Node(
        title="node1 changed", group_id=g2,
        children=[
            Leaf(id=l2, title="g2 only"),
            Leaf(id=l3, title="both groups"),
        ]
    )

    session.add_all([n11, n21])
    session.commit()


def find_changed_leaves(group_id_a, group_id_b):
    """
    Leaves which are in both versions, but a `title` for their parents is changed.
    """
    NodeA = aliased(Node, name='node_a')
    NodeB = aliased(Node, name='node_b')
    LeafA = aliased(Leaf, name='leaf_a')
    LeafB = aliased(Leaf, name='leaf_b')

    query = (
        session.query(LeafA, LeafB)
        .filter(LeafA.group_id == group_id_a)
        # @note: group membership for LeafB is part of join now
        .join(LeafB, (LeafA.id == LeafB.id) & (LeafB.group_id == group_id_b))

        .join(NodeA, LeafA.parent)
        .join(NodeB, LeafB.parent)

        # Filter for modified parents
        .filter(NodeA.title != NodeB.title)
    )
    return query.all()


def find_orphaned_leaves(group_id_a, group_id_b):
    """
    Leaves found in group A, but not in group B.
    """
    LeafA = aliased(Leaf, name='leaf_a')
    LeafB = aliased(Leaf, name='leaf_b')

    query = (
        session.query(LeafA)
        .filter(~(
            session.query(LeafB)
            .filter(LeafA.id == LeafB.id)
            .filter(group_id_b == LeafB.group_id)
            .exists()
        ))

        # Group membership
        .filter(LeafA.group_id == group_id_a)
    )
    return query.all()


def find_deleted_leaves(group_id_a, group_id_b):
    a_s = find_orphaned_leaves(group_id_a, group_id_b)
    return tuple((a, None) for a in a_s)

def find_added_leaves(group_id_a, group_id_b):
    b_s = find_orphaned_leaves(group_id_b, group_id_a)
    return tuple((None, b) for b in b_s)


# add test data
_add_test_data()

# check the results
changed = find_changed_leaves(g1, g2)
assert 1 == len(changed)
le, ri = changed[0]
assert le.id == ri.id == l3

added = find_added_leaves(g1, g2)
assert 1 == len(added)
le, ri = added[0]
assert le is None
assert ri.id == l2

deleted = find_deleted_leaves(g1, g2)
assert 1 == len(deleted)
le, ri = deleted[0]
assert le.id == l1
assert ri is None
```

Comment: Thanks! I had come to the same conclusion; nice to have it validated. And thanks for going to the effort of making the test case. I should have made the bounty bigger :)

Comment: I didn't realise you could join on relationships, like `.join(NodeA, LeafA.parent)`. That's really cool.